# Disabling "Low GPU Memory" Notification in Gnome

Tags: centos, memory, gnome3, gpu, notifications

How can I disable the notifications that warn for low available GPU memory? A screenshot is included below. [image: Low GPU memory notification]

These are very distracting. As I'm never doing anything GPU demanding, the notifications are the only *symptoms* I suffer from low GPU memory. I don't see any other effect of this. So I would like to get rid of these notifications which seem pointless in my case.

(Besides, the notification if probably correct, because the system has only 256 MB GPU memory).

Clicking on them does nothing, and they repeat themselves very regularly (every few minutes). There is no way to disable them in the settings application.
I already found the dconf key `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping`, but this seems to be only about notifications for low disk space. Is there something similar for GPU memory? I would like to not disable notification all together.

I don't have root access on the machine, but could get an administrator to apply a solution if this is the only way.
The system is running Gnome 3.28.3 on Centos7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to disable it unless you un-patch the source code for the `housekeeping` plugin. Apparently [this is a RedHat (and hence CentOS) specific patch](https://git.powerel.org/powerel7/gui/src/commit/ae8381a8d83715a9c4b106a521e32cce6d538969/SOURCES/0001-housekeeping-Add-a-GPU-memory-usage-notification.patch) introduced  by the said distros a few years ago ([see also the discussion here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/380)).

I don't have access to RedHat/CentOS to try it but I'd personally disable the launcher that auto-starts the plugin (the recommended procedure is to copy the system launcher locally adding the [`Hidden=True`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) key-value so that it only affects your user account):

```
launcher=org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop
sed '1a\
Hidden=true' /etc/xdg/autostart/${launcher} > ~/.config/autostart/${launcher}
```