# How to supress specific notification from dbus?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-shell, d-bus, notifications

I'm trying but not understand how to supress notification like this:
[image]

What I have in dbus:

```
method call time=1659640147.068489 sender=:1.46 -> destination=:1.18 serial=63 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "GPU memory"
   uint32 9
   string "utilities-system-monitor-symbolic"
   string "Running low on GPU memory"
   string "GPU memory usage is at 84%. You may free up some memory by closing some applications."
   array [
      string "ignore"
      string "Ignore"
      string "examine"
      string "Examine"
   ]
   array [
   ]
   int32 -1
method call time=1659640177.047328 sender=:1.46 -> destination=:1.18 serial=64 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=CloseNotification
   uint32 9
signal time=1659640177.048047 sender=:1.18 -> destination=(null destination) serial=942 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=NotificationClosed
   uint32 9
   uint32 3
```

I've found this solution: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6806841
But I don't have access to it  :(
I use CentOS stream 8 in my desktop, and gnome-3.32, dbus-daemon-1.12.8

Comment: I've added an [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731412) HTH